# error: element number 2 undefined in return list

Tags: matlab, error-handling, octave

The following function is generating an error.

```
function [retval] = select_red(train, test)
% shuffle test/data points
  shuffled_test = test(randperm(size(test, 1)), :);

  clubs     = shuffled_test(shuffled_test(:, 1) == 1, :);
  diamonds  = shuffled_test(shuffled_test(:, 1) == 2, :);
  hearts    = shuffled_test(shuffled_test(:, 1) == 3, :);
  spades    = shuffled_test(shuffled_test(:, 1) == 4, :);

  clubs = clubs(1: floor(size(clubs,1)/2),:);
  spades = spades(1: floor(size(spades,1)/2),:);

  shuffled_test = [clubs ; diamonds ; hearts ; spades];

  shuffled_test = shuffled_test(randperm(size(shuffled_test, 1)), :);

  ercf_indep = bayescls(train, shuffled_test, @pdfindep, 0.25 * ones(1,4), 0.1);
  ercf_dep = bayescls(train, shuffled_test, @pdfdep, 0.25 * ones(1,4), 0.1);
  ercf_parzen = bayescls(train, shuffled_test, @pdfparzen, 0.25 * ones(1,4), 0.1);

  retval = [ercf_indep   ercf_dep   ercf_parzen];
endfunction
```

**Usage**

```
>> [errindep  errdep  errparzen] = select_red(train, test)
errindep =

    0.1089181   0.0029240   0.2309942

    error: element number 2 undefined in return list
```

**Can you tell why is it generating an error message?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking too much from the poor function. You want three outputs and it can only deliver one (which is a vector containing three numbers).

- If you want the function to produce the three numbers as separate outputs, declare it as

  ```
  [ercf_indep, ercf_dep, ercf_parzen] = select_red(train, test)
  ```

  and remove the line `retval = ...` at the end.
- If you don't want to modify the function, you need to call it with one output:

  ```
  out = select_red(train, test);
  ```

  Then unpack that output into three numbers:

  ```
  ercf_indep_out = out(1)
  ercf_dep =  out(2);
  ercf_parzen = out(3);
  ```

  Or the unpacking can be done using a comma-separated list generated from a cell array:

  ```
  out_cell = num2cell(out);
  [ercf_indep_out, ercf_dep, ercf_parzen] = out_cell{:}
  ```